# Need to construct a CodeIgniter DB query that uses like and not_like both...?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i need to construct a codeIgniter DB query that use **like()** and **not_like()**
both, is it possible?

or an alternative would be use **like()** but has to be case sensitive

currently, here's the model code

```
function getLocation($like) {
    $this->db->like('address', $like);
    $q = $this->db->get('Retailers');
    if($q->num_rows() > 0) etc. etc…..
```

and in the controller uses it like this.

```
public function locations() {
    $this->load->model('location_model');
    $data['search_city_keys']['Brooklyn']=$this->location_model-    >getLocation("Brooklyn");
    $data['search_city_keys']['Manhattan']=$this->location_model->getLocation("New York");
$data['search_city_keys']['Michigan']=$this->location_model->getLocation("MI"); /* PROBLEMS */
```

when looking for addresses in Michigan (MI), it's pulling up NY address with 'mi' in the street address, like Smith Street.
so the pseudo code would be 
    like('MI') but_not_like('New York');

yes it would make sense to have a better table, like a state column but i cannot do that as it uses a Google Map app. this is how Google says to do it, or else their map display won't work.

Comment: Don't write subpar code to hack around a problem when you don't need to. I'm willing to bet there's a much more normalized solution that would be perfectly compatible with whatever Google Maps is expecting. Seeing as how it's YOUR local DB and not Google's, I doubt their restraint is what's stopping you.

Comment: ok now i'm just trying to write a reg. msyql query using like and not like. Select * from retailers where address like '%mi%' and address not like '%ny%'; but it's returning empty CORRECTION: it IS working

Comment: correction: it IS working